# Error: SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, tls1.2, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to make a POST request with httpWebRequest on Https endpoint but this gives me exception like:

```
System.Net.WebException "SecureChannelFailure (The authentication or decryption has failed.)"
```

`Xamarin` `Mac` Project's target framework is : `Mono/.Net 4.5`

```
Mono Framework:4.8.1
```

Here is myh code snippet:

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())) // i'm getting exception on this line.
{
string json = jsonWhere;
streamWriter.Write(json);
}
```

My Application was working fine 1 day ago and I didn't make any changes but now I'm getting this error.

Comment: app is not working on my machine and as well as on user's machine. Is there any relation with client machine's browser certificate?